# Not getting unified_receipt in Apple iOS In App Purchase Server-to-Server Notification Sandbox

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, server-to-server

I am not getting **`unified_receipt`** as said in the developer documentation in the sandbox of apple in app purchase receipts.

As per their documentation : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications/responsebody

> Important
>
> The following top-level objects are scheduled for deprecation:
>   latest_receipt, latest_receipt_info, latest_expired_receipt, and
>   latest_expired_receipt_info. Update any existing code to rely on the
>   following objects in unified_receipt instead: latest_receipt and
>   latest_receipt_info.

But in my response, I am not getting `unified_receipt`.

Comment: It's the same for me. Did you find any new information regarding this?

Comment: I have raised a ticket with Apple Developer support but they didn't replied to me yet.

Comment: @ParthPatel did you get any response from Apple? I'm experiencing the same thing. Could you link your Apple ticket here, so we could track it?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you will only see the `unified_receipt` when you receive the notifications at the endpoint that you've set up in the AppStore Connect. [More info here](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev0067a330b)

Hope this helps!!!